# EnvelopeApi.CreateEnvelope() (docusign) throws an USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED exception

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am using the docusign C# client (https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client).

1. The same code works in the staging (demo.docusign.net) environment, but fails in the production (www.docusign.net) environment.
2. The same user credentials works with the older docusign sdk (DocuSign.Integration.Client.dll, v1.7.2), but fails with the latest docusign sdk (DocuSign.eSign.dll, v2.0.1)

Here is my code:

```
var accountId = LoginAndGetAccountId();

var envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition
{
    EmailSubject = "Please sign this agreement.",
    Status = "sent"
};

...
...

var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
var envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelopeDefinition);
```

I can log in via the API, and get a valid account id. The code bombs with the production environment when I make the "envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope()" call.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException' occurred in DocuSign.eSign.dll

Additional information: Error calling CreateEnvelope: {
    "errorCode": "USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
    "message": "One or both of Username and Password are invalid."
}
```

How can I debug this further?

Comment: Has your integration key been certified for use on the production platform?

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned above, I have code running in production with the older sdk (DocuSign.Integration.Client.dll, v1.7.2). I am trying to get my code working with the newer SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Login() API call is used to authenticate against the API and retrieve your `baseUrl` and `accountId`.  You'll notice that the `baseUrl` that is returned contains the proper server where your user/account reside.

When you make the Login call against production what value is brought back?  Since you are getting a user authentication error I think the value is NOT `www` but rather `eu1` or `na2` I'm guessing.  Can you confirm which domain is being returned and that you are making production calls against the correct server?

Note: All this info is contained in the POST API Certification guide:  https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/API_Certification_Post_04_08_16.pdf

Comment: Found the issue and how to fix it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To anyone struggling with this, the answer is frustrating simple.

My program worked great when the base URL was pointed to demo.docusign.net/restapi.

I had been approved to use the API, my production environment had been setup with a paid prescription and users. Then I updated my code to use the new users and passwords.

In the documentation, there is a note that says to change the base URL in your code to www.docusign.com/restapi when you are ready to switch over to production. So I made that change as well.

Then I would get the error mentioned by the OP. If I switched it back to the URL for development there was no problem.

To solve the issue - don't use www. **Use either na2, eu1 or eu.** Simple as that.

To find out which one to use, go to your account in the Docusign portal and enable logging. Download the log and at the files in the log there should be a reference to na2, eu1, or eu at the top.

Like this:

```
PUT https://na2.docusign.net:....
```